# pointer in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to print a filename which contains decimal point numbers...
say

```
 L2.3stop.txt
```

I have variables defined as :

```
 z1=2.3
 z2=3.4
 z3=7.8
 z4=8.9
```

and so on

In a for loop i runs from 1 to 5

Inside the loop if I do

```
 temp=`echo z$i`
```

and then I print the file name using

```
 echo L${temp}stop.txt
```

it just prints

```
 Lz1stop.txt
 Lz2stop.txt
```

etc..

How can I print the desired filename....

I also tried using

```
 echo L$((z$i))stop.txt
```

but this only works when z1, z2, z3 etc are integers and not floating numbers....

Comment: Did you know that Bash has [arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
z1=2.3
z2=3.4
z3=7.8
z4=8.9

for i in {1..4};do
        echo L$(eval "echo \$z"$i)stop.txt
done
```

or this should work too:

```
for i in {1..4};do
    echo L$(echo $(echo "\$z$i"))stop.txt
done
```

outputs:

```
L2.3stop.txt
L3.4stop.txt
L7.8stop.txt
L8.9stop.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not portable, but in bash you can do:

```
name=z$i
echo ${!name}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best (using an array):

```
z=( 2.3 3.4 7.8 8.9 9.8 ) # Added fifth value
for x in "${z[@]}"
do
    echo L${x}stop.txt
done
```

Less good (using [indirect expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) — a `bash` feature):

```
z1=2.3
z2=3.4
z3=7.8
z4=8.9
z5=9.8  # Added fifth value

for i in {1..5}
do
    v=z$i
    echo L${!v}stop.txt
done
```

Both produce:

```
L2.3stop.txt
L3.4stop.txt
L7.8stop.txt
L8.9stop.txt
L9.8stop.txt
```

Both avoid using `eval` which is not too harmful in this context but is dangerous (and difficult to use correctly) in general.

Answer (score 2):

If you have defined variable `z`, you can do this:

```
for v in ${!z*}; do echo L${!v}stop.txt; done
```

or:

```
for v in z{1..4}; do echo L${!v}stop.txt; done
```